# is this a safe way to change character set on a MySQL table to UTF-8

Tags: mysql, sql, database, utf-8

I need to change the character set on two MySQL tables to UTF8. Initially I came up with the following query but I wanted to know if this is a safe way to change the character set on (live) tables which have foreign keys. In my dev environment I just used the "FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0" without the lock but i wasn't so concerned about integrity at the time, with the live system I am.

```
LOCK TABLES 
  tags WRITE,
  tags_lost WRITE;

  SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

    ALTER TABLE myDB.exampleTable CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
    ALTER TABLE myDB.exampleTable CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
    ALTER TABLE myDB.exampleTable CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
    ALTER TABLE myDB.exampleTable CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

  SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;    
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

The other option is to lock the tables, drop the foreign key, alter the char set, and then recreate the key but I was just hoping this shortcut would work just as well.

Comment: You don't want to change to UTF8, you want to change to `UTF8mb4`, [please read why that is so](http://stackoverflow.com/a/279279/3536236)

Answer (score 0):

Don't change the charset, only do the `ALTER ... CONVERT TO ...`.  The latter does *both* the declaration and the data.

If you have already done both, check the data:

```
SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM exampleTable WHERE ...
```

and let's see if the hex is correct.  You could have ended up with the dreaded "double encoding".